# EPIServer CMS Development

Tags: episerver, episerver-8

Hi I just started looking on EPiServer CMS and like to know is there any EPIServer certification practice tests available?

I have only checked EPiServer CMS portion, please let me know whether the EPiServer certification exams contains questions from both CMS and Commerce

or

CMS and Commerce certification exams are separate?

Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll get started here, http://www.episerver.com/Training/episerver-certification/

To take pratice tests go to http://episerver.enlight.net/

- Username: practiceuser
- Password: practiceuser2

More information on the tests here, http://www.episerver.com/Training/episerver-certification/exam-information/

*The username and password can sometimes be disabled if someone misspelled the password to many times.*

Comment: Thanks Eric. the URL shows separate knowledge areas for CMS and Commerce. Does this is a single exam or separate certification exams for CMS and Commerce.

Comment: Separate exams.

Answer (score 0):

I just passed the Episerver a few of weeks ago. The CMS and Commerce certification exams are separate exam. I didn't use any EPIServer certification practice tests. However, there are a few of resources you might have a look at in below:

```
* EPiServer World: http://world.episerver.com
* User Guides for EPiServer CMS https://world.episerver.com/documentation/Items/user-guides/
* Users Guide for Editors (PDF)
* Users Guide for Administrators (PDF)
* System Requirements: http://world.episerver.com/documentation/Items/System-Requirements/System-Requirements---EPiServer/
* Developer’s Guide for EPiServer CMS: https://world.episerver.com/documentation/developer-guides/CMS/
* Episerver License: https://license.episerver.com/
```